# Como enviar dados de checkbox para uma consulta com mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Eu não sei como começar toda esse processo de enviar vários dados para uma consulta no banco de dados. Eu sempre envio um item de cada **tipos** mas nunca enviei vários itens de um mesmo **tipo**. A imagem abaixo vai exemplificar melhor:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que me ajudassem com conceitos para que eu consiga chegar ao resultado desejado. Eu  imagino que tenha tudo haver com captura de valores e estocagem das variáveis em **arrays** mas não sei muito mais coisa que isso.

Para a lógica, acho que eu selecionaria imóveis de todas as cidades apresentadas, depois tipo de imóvel e depois quantidade de dormitórios, pelo menos acho que seria assim. Gostaria de saber todo o processo desde o `HTML` até a consulta.

Modificação: coloquei nesta url http://axitech.com.br/_testes/checkbox.php o que eu fiz até agora. Fiz o `HTML` dos três resultados que tenho que capturar com PHP em forma de **array**.

```
</body> 
    <form> 
        <p>Selecione a cidade: </p> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="cidade[]" value="Campo Grande">Campo Grande<br> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="cidade[]" value="Dourados">Dourados<br> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="cidade[]" value="Três Lagoas">Três Lagoas<br> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="cidade[]" value="Corumbá">Corumbá<br> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="cidade[]" value="Naviraí">Naviraí<br> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="cidade[]" value="Paranaíba">Paranaíba<br> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="cidade[]" value="Aquidauana">Aquidauana<br><br>         

        <p>Tipo de imóvel: </p> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="imovel[]" value="Apartamento">Apartamento<br> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="imovel[]" value="Casa">Casa<br> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="imovel[]" value="Comercial">Comercial<br> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="imovel[]" value="Terreno">Terreno<br> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="imovel[]" value="Condomínio">Condomínio<br><br> 

        <p>Selecione a quantidade de dormitórios: </p> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="dormitorios[]" value="1 Dormitório">1 Dormitório<br> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="dormitorios[]" value="2 Dormitórios">2 Dormitórios<br> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="dormitorios[]" value="3 Dormitórios">3 Dormitórios<br> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="dormitorios[]" value="4 Dormitórios">4 Dormitórios<br> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="dormitorios[]" value="5 Dormitórios">5 Dormitórios<br> 
    </form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você planeja fazer algum como um SELECT, poderia usar o IN, baseando-se no array obtido.
Você poderia fazer assim:

```
    $parseInQuery = function(array $array){
        return '`' . implode('`,`', $array) . '`';
    };

    // Condições para execução da consulta

    $queryData = $parseInQuery($_POST['cidade']);
    echo $query = "SELECT *  FROM tabela WHERE nome IN($queryData)";

   // imprime: SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE nome IN(`Campo Grande`,`Minas Gerais`)
```

Nessa caso eu utilizei uma *função anônima* para criar uma função dentro de $parseInQuery, para converter o Array para os elementos selecionados em um "In" do MYSQL.

Assim também funcionaria:

```
if (!empty($_POST['cidade'])) {
    $queryData = '`' . implode('`,`', $_POST['cidade']) . '`';
}
```

**Atualização:**

Tendo em vista a necessidade de múltiplos dados nessa consulta, elaborei a seguinte forma, que conta com a segurança do `filter_input`

```
function parseMysqlQuery($array)
{
    $output = '';

    foreach( $array as $key => $value){
       $output .= !$output ? " WHERE $key " : " AND $key ";
       $output .= 'IN(`' . implode('`,`', $value) . '`)';
    }

    return $output;

}
$array = (array)filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, array(
    'cidade' => array(
        'filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
        'flags'  => FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY,
    ),
    'imovel' => array(
        'filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
        'flags'  => FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY,
    ),

    'dormitorios' => array(
        'filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
        'flags'  => FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY,
    ),
));


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    $array = array_filter($array);

    $in = parseMysqlQuery($array);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM tabela " . $in;

    // SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE bairro IN(`Ibirité`) AND dormitorios IN(`1 quarto`)

    echo $query;
}
```

Comment: No caso do meu código apresentado nesse link http://axitech.com.br/_testes/checkbox.php aonde o `foreach` pega os dados das `checkboxs`, quem seria meu `$array`?

Comment: $_POST['cidades'], pois quando você usa a instrução "cidades[]" você cria a seguinte estrutura: $_POST = array('cidades' => array(0 => 'primeira', 1 => 'segunda'))

Comment: No caso, você tem um array multidimensional, onde $_POST['cidade'], $_POST['dormitorio'] e $_POST['dormitorios'] se tratam de arrays. Tente usar `var_export` em $_POST para checar essa informação

Comment: Beleza, mas agora lembre-se que eu posso receber mais de um `array`, até vários. Eu tenho que fazer um `select` de cada vez pegando o resultado anterior como base ou posso fazer todos os `selects` juntos ou mesmo usar `if/else`? Tipo, se houver cidade, faz o próximo `select`?!?!?!

Comment: Só reforçando: O `array $array` é o argumento da função anônima $parseInQuery. $_POST['cidades'] é passado como argumento em seguida para obter o trecho do código MYSQL em `$queryData`

Comment: Tá mas eu tenho `cidade`, `imovel`, `dormitorio`, como juntar os 3 num `select` só?

Comment: Caso algum array esteja vazio, isso vai gerar algum erro ou simplesmente será ignorado pelo `select`?

Answer (score 2):

Você tem duas etapas para resolver:

1. Acessar os dados da requisição
2. Montar a query SQL

Vou dar respostas rápidas que podem te guiar.

Para acessar os dados já comentaram acima você simples sua `$_POST['cidades']` e já tem um array com as cidades. Simples

Para montar a query e filtrar na base de dados você vai usar Join, In e Where. Exemplo:

```
select i.nome from imovel i join cidade c where c.nome in ("Campo Grande","Paranaíba") and i.tipo in ("Casa","Apartamento") and i.dormitorio in ("4","5")
```

Para montar uma query como essa, você "pode" fazer no PHP concatenação de strings, isso vai abrir sua aplicação para SQL Injection uma falha de segurança grave, mas é a alternativa é uma longa história e vai dependender de como está construindo a aplicação. Sugido usar *Doctrine 2* para acesso a dados

Com relação a query de exemplo o nome da cidade não é uma boa prática, o ideal é ter um id como número representando a cidade seu formulário ficaria assim

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cidade[]" value="1672">Aquidauana<br><br>
```

Repare que value agora é um número que representa a chave primária na base de dados. O mesmo se aplica para o tipo do imóvel, no exemplo eu considerei que está na mesma tabela, mas na prática é melhor ter uma tabela separada e fazer o join das 3. Já que isso segue as práticas de normalização e o tipo independe do imóvel podendo variar e ser alterado (se alguém cadastrar um tipo com nome errado e alterá-lo depois que a aplicação já salvou imóveis vai dar problema)

Comment: Primeiro a `query` seleciona todas as cidades dos imóveis, logo após de todas as cidades dos imóveis extraídas a `query` seleciona todos os tipos e imóveis e o que sobrar a `query` extraí os resultados que correspondem a quantidade de dormitórios, certo?

Comment: Correto, por debaixo dos panos é mais eficiente, pois o banco de dados não precisa retornar todas as cidades para depois filtrar ele monta uma arvore de decisão, mas sua lógica de interpretação está correta.