# Como fazer esta requisição SQL com esta particularidade?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Nesta busca quando o array retorna o `4` conforme a SQL demonstrada mais abaixo, eu preciso que o sistema retorna todos os resultado cujo a quantidade de dormitórios e `>= 4`. Podem me ajudar a chegar neste resultado.

Converti a coluna para `INT`. Tá feia a coisa na `DB`, não fui eu quem fiz, estava pronta.

```
# Selecionando conforme quantidade de dormitorios
$dormi = $_POST['dorm'];
if (isset($_POST['dorm']) && is_array($_POST['dorm']) && count($_POST['dorm']) > 0){

    $where .= " DORMITORIO IN (". implode(', ', $dormi).") AND ";
    if (in_array(4, $_POST['dorm'])){

        $where .= trim($where,' AND ').' OR DORMITORIO >= 4 AND ';

    }

}
```

Este é o SQL resutaldo desta busca:

> SELECT * FROM imovel WHERE 1=1 AND DORMITORIO IN (1, 2, 3, 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
if (isset($_POST['dorm']) && is_array($_POST['dorm']) && count($_POST['dorm']) > 0){

   if (in_array('4', $_POST['dorm'])) {

      $where .= " ( DORMITORIO IN ('".implode("', '", $_POST['dorm'])."') OR DORMITORIO > 4 ) AND ";

   } else $where .= " DORMITORIO IN ('".implode("', '", $_POST['dorm'])."') AND ";

}
```

Assim, mesmo que o usuário selecione as opções `2, 4`, o retorno será consistente:

> SELECT * FROM imovel WHERE 1=1 AND DORMITORIO IN ('2','4') OR DORMITORIO > 4

Mas caso você queria que ao selecionar a opção `4`, mostre apenas os registros com dormitórios maior ou igual a 4, faça assim:

```
if (isset($_POST['dorm']) && is_array($_POST['dorm']) && count($_POST['dorm']) > 0){

   if (in_array('4', $_POST['dorm'])) {
      $where .= ' DORMITORIO >= 4 AND ';
   } else {
      $where .= " DORMITORIO IN ('".implode("', '", $_POST['dorm'])."') AND ";
   }

}
```

Assim, se o usuário selecionar as opções `2, 4`, o retorno será:

> SELECT * FROM imovel WHERE 1=1 AND DORMITORIO >= 4

<sub>Obs.: Recomendo usar uma classe que fornece opções para criação de filtros dinâmicos, [como essa](https://github.com/KaduAmaral/ConnectionMSi#where).</sub>

Comment: Fatal Error: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a 'WHERE 1=1 AND DORMITORIO IN ('4') OR DORMITORIO > 4' na linha 1 ...

Comment: Não identifiquei nenhum erro ai, fiz um teste aqui e deu normal... Coloca o SQL gerado completo ai pra ver o que está dando errado.

Comment: Isso no banco funciona: `SELECT * FROM imovel WHERE 1 =1 AND DORMITORIO IN ('1',  '2',  '3',  '4') OR DORMITORIO > 4` ... na requisição, não ! Deve ser erro na SQL dinâmica.

Comment: Kadu, consegue ver aonde está dando erro? Seleciono o `4` e dá erro >>>> http://puu.sh/c3kAx/d13eb5844e.png

Comment: Fiz uma atualização ali no código, veja se resolve. A principio não vejo nenhum erro de syntax... :/

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa fazer uma rotina que gere:

```
SELECT * FROM imovel WHERE dormitorio >= 4
```

em vez de `IN`. Não faz o mínimo sentido usar `IN` neste caso.

Você pode definir os options do form como sendo 1,2,3 e 4, e usar uma `array` neste formato para gerar a *query* :

```
$opcoes = Array( '>= 0', '= 1', '= 2', '= 3', '>= 4' );
```

assim, basta fazer:

```
$dormi = 0 + @$_POST['dorm']; // A supressão é aceitável neste contexto
$dormi = $dormi>4 ? 4 : $dormi;
$opcoes = Array( '>= 0', '= 1', '= 2', '= 3', '>= 4' );

$where .= ' DORMITORIO '.$opcoes[$dormi];
```

e os resultados para 0, 1, 2, 3 e 4 serão respectivamente estes:

```
WHERE DORMITORIO >= 0
WHERE DORMITORIO = 1
WHERE DORMITORIO = 2
WHERE DORMITORIO = 3 
WHERE DORMITORIO >= 4
```

Não deixa de ser um *reparo técnico*  <sup>1</sup>, então sugiro otimizar para o seu caso pratico.

<sub><sup>1. Gambiarra</sup></sub>

Comment: @Bacco , acho que ele envia essas dados com `checkbox`, onde pode ter várias opções selecionadas.

Comment: Talvez, mas é um tanto estranho alguém querer uma casa com 1 ou 4 dormitórios apenas... E olhe que eu já atendi uma série de imobiliárias. Mas vai saber né? :)

Comment: Pois é, rs... Aqui tem outra pergunta dele, acho que é do mesmo sistema. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31319/como-enviar-dados-de-checkbox-para-uma-consulta-com-mysql

Comment: @Bacco pode ser estranho quem está procurando 1 quarto procurar por 4 ao mesmo tempo mas não é tão estranho procurar por 3 e 4. E se eu colocar `>=4` elimino 75% dos imóveis da busca pois estes são de 3 quartos pelo menos neste sistema.

Comment: @MarcosVinicius claro, você deve fazer o que for conveniente. É que nestes casos geralmente o pessoal adota o mínimo (de 1 pra cima, de 2 pra cima, de 3 pra cima) pois quem procura 2, provavelmente vai aceitar uma casa com 3 quartos, mas não o inverso. No seu caso em específico, é claro que você deve fazer da melhor forma que agrade seu cliente.

Comment: Tem extrema lógica o que falou !!!

Comment: Ai a query fica mais simples ainda, nao precisa do array. `WHERE DORMITORIO > '.(0+@$_POST['dorm']);` (Usei o melhor do estilo **[XGH](http://goo.gl/lZ37UE)** pra bolar esse código do comment :D )